# Auto pick a file in VBA and run the rest of the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that autoruns and works well and I want to transform it a little. I was able to build this much with Google's help.

But the code needs me to pick a file manually but I need to auto pick a file and that is fixed. So I want to specify a path to the specific file but I am not able to do that.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My attempt below.

````
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Dim Path As String
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Path = "C:\Users\x\x\xx\c.xlsx"
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Worksheets("Results").UsedRange
        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Range("A1")
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Not sure what your code is supposed to do. You are trying to copy the contents of the "Results" sheet in the active workbook to the "Results" sheet in the workbook at "C:\Users\x\x\xx\c.xlsx"? Does that destination workbook already have a "Results" sheet?

Comment: @sigil My code is trying to get data from "Results" Sheet from one workbook and pasting into the "A2" cell  of the curent workbook where the VBA code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path and filename are fixed then this should work:

```vb
Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim xWb As Workbook, xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xAddWb As Workbook
    Dim Path As String

    Set xWs = ActiveSheet

    Path = "C:\Users\x\x\xx\c.xlsx"
    Set xAddWb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    xAddWb.Worksheets("Results").UsedRange.Copy xWs.Range("A1")
    xWs.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    xAddWb.Close False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Get_File()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'Open both workbooks first:

Set y = ActiveWorkbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\x\x\xx\c.xlsx")

'Now, copy what you want from x:

x.Sheets("Results").Range("A1").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:

y.Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'Close x:

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works and I have upvoted it as well but it will take sometime to reflect. Thank you